# Azure Emulator Cache

Tags: azure, azure-compute-emulator

Having an issue running a web role locally using the azure emulator. It hangs indefinitely and the only error I see is in the **Application Server-Applications/Operational** event logs. I've checked the versions of all DLLs and SDK's.

Occasionally I'll see ErrorCode ERRCA0009 :SubStatus ES0001 or a request timeout.

Azure SDK 1.8.1 VS2012 on Windows 8.

```
Handling an exception. Exception details: System.NullReferenceException: 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Microsoft.Windows.Azure.DevFabric.DevFabricManagement.GetTenantDetails
(String tenantName)
at SyncInvokeGetTenantDetails(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke
(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5
(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31
(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

Comment: If anyone is interested I 'fixed' this by ditching the Azure Distributed cache and using Redis.